# Jest didn't parse to import a file

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, next.js

I am trying to test my Next.js project with Jest and Enzyme. When I try to **import** a file from my components to test it, throws error though. Here's my files...

**In the package.json my jest configuration are:**

```
 "jest": {
"setupFilesAfterEnv": "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/.next/",
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
],
"transform": {
  "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "jest-transform-graphql",
  ".*": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
}


 },

  "//": "I prefer this over a .babelrc file",
  "babel": {
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "presets": [
          "next/babel"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
            "styled-components",
            {
              "ssr": true,
              "displayName": true
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "production": {
        "presets": [
          "next/babel"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
            "styled-components",
            {
              "ssr": true,
              "displayName": true
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "test": {
        "presets": [
          [
            "next/babel",
            {
              "preset-env": {
                "modules": "commonjs"
              }
            }
          ]
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
            "styled-components",
            {
              "ssr": true,
              "displayName": true
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**And  subsequently in jest.setup.js :**

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

**However I always encounter this error anytime I want to **import a file** **(In here for example I try to import a file namely "import ItemComponent from '../components/Item';"):

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest
>   cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
>
> By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform
>   your files, ignoring "node_modules". SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   identifier

Details:

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Welcome\Desktop\Advanced-React-master\sick-fits\frontend\__tests__\Item.test.js: Unexpected token (20:28)

  18 | describe('<Item/>', () => {
  19 |   it('renders and matches the snapshot', () => {
> 20 |     const wrapper = shallow(<ItemComponent item={fakeItem} />);
     |                             ^
  21 |     expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  22 |   });
  23 |   // it('renders and displays properly', () => {

  at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3939:15)
  at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5248:16)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6328:20)
  at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5924:21)
  at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5903:21)
  at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5812:21)
  at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5784:21)
  at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5731:21)
  at Parser.parseExprListItem (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6995:18)
  at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6124:22)
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing these two lines from your `package.json`:

```
  ".*": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
```

In theory, these shouldn't be needed: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object

The custom configuration you have added might be causing issues. In theory, `jest` should transform your `js` files by default using `babel-jest`. I've certainly had a recent NextJS project work with jest with no `babel-jest` config declared in my `package.json`.

Comment: I try omitting those two lines in my package.json, but it doesn't resolve the issue, the error above remains the same..

Comment: Ok, I'm sure it's your babel config. Under the `"test"` part of your babel config in your `package.json` try making it just `"presets": ["next/babel"]`. I have working tests with a `babel.config.js` file with just `module.exports = { presets: ['next/babel'] };`. Removing that declaration for me gives me exactly the same error as you. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config You shouldn't have to customise the babel config - you just need to get it to use Next's default babel config.

Comment: I had lots of problems too - was a lot of pain and effort to get everything working as it should. If all else fails, you could use my implementation as reference here: https://github.com/Yorkshireman/github-api-nextjs

Comment: Thanks, it resolved. Although it doesn't work if I only set what inside of test case of the babel was, but also have to remove all the cases of "env", "production" &"test" too. Another thing weird is that it doesn't recognize configuration in the file jest.setup.js and I have to reenter them in every test.js file.

Comment: Thanks, it resolved. Although it doesn't work if I only set what inside of “test” case of the babel was, but also have to remove all the cases of "env", "production" & "test".
Another thing weird is it doesn't recognize configuration in the file jest.setup.js hence I have to assign those in every test.js file in which enzyme must be called...

Comment: Great! What exactly is the solution? Then I can update my answer.

Comment: Strange thing about the jest.setup.js - it might be something to do with your folder structure

Comment: I think it may be due to one of these in my package.json:
EITHER
`"scripts": {
"test": "SET NODE_ENV=test && jest --watch",
}`

OR
`"jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
    ],`

And for remembrance the file jest.setup.js (which is in my root directory):
`import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });`

however it doesn’t recognized (…so I had to put it on every test file separately)